# MS Graph : Get-MgPrivilegedAccess for Azure

Tags: azure, powershell, microsoft-graph-api

Does anybody know how the cmdlet Get-MgPrivilegedAccess works ?
What I am supposed to write for the parameter -PrivilegedAccessId ?
I try to get all the ressources with a RBAC assignment, active or elligible.

No information on the web, and Microsoft documentation is not very full.

Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I answer myself :
I use the cmdlet Get-MgPrivilegedAccessResource
with the parameter -PrivilegedAccessId : "azureResources"

and it works :)